# OpenGL Cheat Sheet?

Tags: opengl, pipeline

First of all, I need to clarify that I'm not after the [OpenGL Quick Reference Sheet](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl-quick-reference-card.pdf).

Has anyone come by a flow-chart-like cheat sheet for OpenGL rendering pipeline? I'm talking about the sheets like these:

[image]

[image]

If not, what's the closest I can get aside from the official quick reference sheet?

Comment: Great sheet! Do you have a newer one you could share? This sheet should be mandatory on official GL/D3D books!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/state.pdf

A bit outdated, but still quite valuable imo.

Comment: Better than nothing. I don't think this topic is going to generate more answers any time soon, so I will accept your answer as something new to me. Thanks a bunch. `:]`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't look at this if you are working with OpenGL 2.0 or newer. While it is still basically correct, the way things should be done has changed a lot since these early days. Use the D3D charts instead. They call things by different names, but the flow is the same as in OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Kilgard has a couple of those rendering pipeline charts in [some of his recent talks on OpenGL 3 and 4](http://www.slideshare.net/Mark_Kilgard/gtc-2010-opengl).

http://www.slideshare.net/Mark_Kilgard